# How to trigger unmounting of functional components while testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I used "useEffect" to achieve functionality of "componentWillUnmount" in functional component. How to trigger that while testing the component using Jest/Enzyme?

My Component:

```
const myComp = () => {
  useEffect(() => () => {
    console.log('Unmounted');
  }, []);
  return <div>Test</div>;
}
```

Comment: @slideshowp2, thanks for your reply. You may not noticed I put console.log in return function, not in the callback. Or can you show me the right way...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086#issuecomment-488215017), we know that `shallow` render doesn't support the `useEffect` hook. We need to use `mount` and call [.unmount()](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/unmount.html) method manually.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export const MyComp = () => {
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      console.log('Unmounted');
    },
    []
  );
  return <div>Test</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { MyComp } from './';

describe('67384129', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComp />);
    wrapper.unmount();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67384129/index.test.tsx (8.233 s)
  67384129
    ✓ should pass (53 ms)

  console.log
    Unmounted

      at examples/67384129/index.tsx:6:15

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.121 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0"
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. wrapper.unmount. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using react-testing-library then:

```html
const { unmount } = render(<Component />);
unmount();
```